# How do I stop iTerm2 from running xcodebuild and hanging when I open a window?

Tags: xcodebuild, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

Since this morning, on my iMac *(macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6)* any time I open an iTerm2 window *(with Oh My Zsh installed)*, I see this:

[image: iTerm2 window running xcodebuild and stuck]

It seems that it's trying to run `xcodebuild` and it's stuck. I never get a prompt, even after waiting a long time. I've tried pressing `ctrl+C` to end the process, and then I see this:

[image: iTerm2 window after pressing cmd+C]

I'm not purposely trying to do anything with Xcode. I just want to use the command line. I've been working for months without this problem, and it just started today. Any suggestion for how I can resolve this and use iTerm like normal?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I had the similar issue.
This resolved the problem:

```
 # sudo xcodebuild -license accept
```

Comment: Such an annoying usability glitch!  IIRC this used to display a screenful of license text and you had to type "yes" to accept, so I can see how "useful" a hang would be in its place... :-/

Comment: Thx that did the trick!

Comment: Thanks a lot, at first I thought it was nvm but this did the trick.

Answer (score 10):

I have got the same issue after updating my MBP16 with Big Sur today

I have checked my xcode command tools path with `xcode-select -p` and I found that the path was related to an older version of xcode (10.1 in my case, I do not remember the path, maybe `/Applications/Xcode_10.1.app/Contents/Developer/`).

I have reinstall xcode command tools (`sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` and `xcode-select --install`) and I have switched the xcode command tools path with this command `sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

The issue is resolved now

Answer (score 8):

I got the same issue with macOS Big Sur.

Tried all Google results and nothing works. Eventually, I found it was caused by setting Node.js v8.x as `default` in nvm, alias `default` to `system` will resolve the issue. Although I don't know why nvm need to run `xcodebuild` for Node.js v8.x.

Answer (score 7):

Many answers but at the first start the console is still very slow (15s).

Looking around I found out that somehow `nvm` needs `xcodebuild`.

The slowdown was fixed changing the `nvm` default to `system`

```
nvm alias default system
```

Still not well clear why this is happening, I suggest to figure out trying to change the `nvm` configuration until you obtain the result.

Answer (score 1):

The hanging I was experiencing happened only *once* after reboot, and consequent launches of the shell happened instantly.

I've spent hours debugging this issue. I eventually traced the hanging to homebrew's start script. My finding was that `/usr/bin/git` was slow at start (took 12 secs to load) for some reason and Homebrew used that binary unless another was installed. I installed a newer version of git through Homebrew using `brew install git` and this fixed the issue.

#### Investigation

I could see that the hang causes 100% CPU usage in syspolicyd and I could see a -67062 error at the end of the hang through Console.app (this error means `code object is not signed at all`). Unfortunately, the error log did not point me to a specific file and I had to add `echo`s inside the brew script to isolate the exact location of the hang. It turned out to be an execution of `git`. Installing another version of `git` that would overwrite the default one fixed the problem. I used `brew install git` since homebrew checks its own directory first for a git binary.

I am not exactly sure how/why the code signature of `/usr/bin/git` is broken. It wasn't broken when I first installed Homebrew. It was somehow corrupted later on.